# How does zoneinfo get updated if at all?

Tags: locale, timezone

I have been installing several systems lately have noticed a difference of opinion on how to set time-zones.

[Arch Linux Beginners' Guide](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Beginners%27_Guide#Time_zone) says to use a symlink and the [Gentoo HOW TO Guide](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Localization/HOWTO#Time_zone) says to copy from the shared folder

While this preference might be better for meta I am wondering if these time-zone files get updated.  If they were updated would the new replace the old or would my zone move from America/Dawson_Creek to America/Dawson_Creek.old?

I am wondering as my little pocket time-zone is an oddity and I constantly worry that since Microsoft refuses to acknowledge it we will be absorbed by the Arizona time zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of things:

- Microsoft has no control over the TZDB used by Linux.  The time zones you're using are from the [IANA TZDB](http://www.iana.org/time-zones), which is managed by a community.  Microsoft time zones are very different.  You can find more details in the [timezone tag wiki on StackOverlow](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/timezone/info).
- You don't have any danger of `America/Dawson_Creek` being deprecated.  That would go against the policies and principles of this database.  If for some reason it was determined that it was no longer needed, then this zone would be converted into a *link* to the new one to maintain backwards compatibility.  If this were to happen, it is highly unlikely that you'd be merged with `America/Phoenix`, because zones in this database don't typically span multiple countries.
- In general, the `tzdata` package is available on most distributions, and gets updated in the same way that other packages get updated.  The changes originate with IANA, and then get packaged up by the tzdata maintainers for linux, and by many others for various systems.  You can find tzdata updates [for ArchLinux here](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/any/tzdata/), [for Ubuntu here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tzdata), [as an RPM package here](http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=tzdata), and several others.  [On Gentoo, it's in the sys-libs/timezone-data package.](http://packages.gentoo.org/package/sys-libs/timezone-data)
- I am not 100% familiar with the differences between those two distributions of Linux with regards to how to *set* the time zone, but it's certainly possible that different distros could have different mechanisms for that.  Perhaps someone else can answer this part of the question more specifically.

Comment: The MS control was a statement of politics and worry more than anything.  As stated the diff between preference is likely an opinion questions which tends to be banned outside of meta.  This is what I was looking for thanks.

Comment: Sure.  But I hope you understand that the IANA time zone database is very anti-political.  There have been many attempts to sway it one way or another for political motivations, which have mostly failed.   Take a look at [time zones in Indiana](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_in_Indiana) for example.  The IANA TZDB still maintains multiple sub-region zones, even though all of the same regions could now be handled by `America/Chicago` or `America/New_York`.  Since at *some* point in their history they differed, they are still unique zones, so they won't disappear.